# jQuery pop ups without using third party jQuery libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery, what are the possible ways to create pop up boxes using jQuery?

While searching in google I came across modal, is there any alternates to this? I prefer to use jQuery pop ups than going for third party jQuery tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi look at the jQuery Dialog which gives you Modal functionality. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog)